# pyInstaller AttributeError: module 'nbt' has no attribute 'world'

Tags: python, pyinstaller

When trying to run script packed with pyInstaller I get
`AttributeError: module 'nbt' has no attribute 'world'`
on line 1 which is `from nbt import nbt`.

This happens both on Linux and Windows.
I tried different imports, like `from nbt.nbt import NBTFile` or `import nbt`.
If I comment out this line, every other import works and the script stops only after hitting first line that uses this import.

The debug messages when running script after packing it with `pyinstaller [name].py -F -d` don't help. Documentation don't help either.

Any hints to what might be causing this?

Using:
Python 3.5
pyInstaller 3.2.1
NBT 1.4.1

Comment: Please verify that PyInstaller has fully installed NBT. There have to be a directory nbt with world.py in it.

Comment: How can I check it?

Comment: Find the directory nbt.

Comment: Where should I look for it? I could not find `nbt` folder anywhere in files created by pyInstaller. It's correctly installed in my virtual environment and works when I run script directly using python.

Comment: That means that PyInstaller has created an incorrect distribution. I think that PyInstaller must be installed into the virtual environment and the environment must be activated before creating a distribution package.

Comment: It's installed inside this virtual environment and I have it activated.

Comment: I just tried to create a distribution from a simple scipt and got the same error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'world'. It seems PyInstaller doesn't add nbt to the distribution. I'll try to find out how to fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you've found an import that PyInstaller doesn't recognize. You should help PyInstaller to find modules either with [.spec file](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html) or with [hooks](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/hooks.html) — see [example](http://pythoncentral.io/pyinstaller-package-python-applications-windows-mac-linux/), section **Using External Modules** — or directly with [hidden import](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html#listing-hidden-imports).

I managed to build a working distribution with command line `pyinstaller --hidden-import nbt.world script.py`.

Comment: Thank you! Previously I tried to use `pyinstaller --hidden-import=nbt script.py` but have not even thought about specifying it so much.